# Page is showing the PHP code rather than running it

Tags: php, html, ajax, apache2

I wrote a simple php script to output the RAM utilization on my server to an HTML page. However when I open the web page I see the php code instead of the expected output.

**HTML Document**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Character set encoding -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- Jquery JS files -->
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AJAX -->
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="statistics">
            <h1>Memory</h1>
            <table>
                <tr><th>Total</th><th>Free</th><th>Used</th></tr>
                <tr id="mem"><script>memDoc()</script></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**AJAX Document**

```
function memDoc() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById('mem').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "free.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

setInterval(function() {
    memDoc()
}, 5000);
```

**PHP Document**

```
<?php
$totalMem = exec("free -m | awk '{print $2}' | awk '(NR==2)'");
$freeMem = exec("free -m | awk '{print $4}' | awk '(NR==2)'");
$usedMem = exec("free -m | awk '{print $3}' | awk '(NR==2)'");
echo "<td>" . $totalMem . "</td><td>" . $freeMem . "</td><td>" . $usedMem . "</td>";
?>
```

I am running Ubuntu Server 15.04 with apache2 (2.4.10-9ubuntu1) and php5 (5.4.6+dfsg-4ubuntu6)[image: This is what the output shows]

Comment: Hows is your HTML file called? if it is named *.html that is what you get, you need to have it named as php file.

Comment: This happens if the PHP document does not have a .php file ending, or if PHP is not installed on the server and/or apache is not configured to process PHP scripts. These are in order of checks too. Goodluck

Comment: The HTML file is named "memory.html" and the php file is named "free.php". Here is the kicker that I forgot to mention in my initial question was that the page did work fine less than 24 hours ago. This is a VM on my workstation so I am the only one who has access to it to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no interpreter for PHP, you should either install mod_php5 or FastCGI

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql
```